# http fuzzing with boofuzz

Tags: python, fuzzing

I was looking for a fuzzing library and I happened to see "boofuzz"
though there are no examples of how to use the library for http fuzzing.

This is the only code I see in their github page, but they say it was taken from sulley (an old fuzzing library):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')

from boofuzz.primitives import String, Static, Delim

class Group(object):
    blocks = []

    def __init__(self, name, definition=None):
        self.name = name
        if definition:
            self.definition = definition

    def add_definition(self, definition):
        assert isinstance(definition, (list, tuple)), "Definition must be a list or a tuple!"
        self.definition = definition

    def render(self):
        return "".join([x.value for x in self.definition])

    def exhaust(self):
        for item in self.definition:
            while item.mutate():
                current_value = item.value
                self.log_send(current_value)
                recv_data = self.send_buffer(current_value)
                self.log_recv(recv_data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%s [%s items]>' % (self.__class__.__name__, len(self.definition))

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def send_buffer(self, current_value):
        return "Sent %s!" % current_value

    def log_send(self, current_value):
        pass

    def log_recv(self, recv_data):
        pass
    s_static = Static
    s_delim  = Delim
    s_string = String

    CloseHeader = Group(
        "HTTP Close Header",
        definition=[
            # GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
            s_static("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"),
            # Connection: close
            s_static("Connection"), s_delim(":"), s_delim(" "), s_string("close"),
            s_static("\r\n\r\n")
        ]
    )

    OpenHeader = Group(
        "HTTP Open Header",
        definition=[
            # GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
            Static("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"),
            # Connection: close
            Static("Connection"), Delim(":"), Delim(" "), String("open"),
            Static("\r\n\r\n")
        ]
    )

    # CloseHeader = Group("HTTP Close Header")
    # CloseHeader.add_definition([
    #     # GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
    #     s_static("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"),
    #     # Connection: close
    #     s_static("Connection"), s_delim(":"), s_delim(" "), s_string("close"),
    #     s_static("\r\n\r\n")
    # ])
```

Why would they post it, if it's another's library code? And is there a good explanation of how to work with the boofuzz library?

Comment: See here for an FTP example: https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz-ftp There is no published HTTP fuzzer with boofuzz to my knowledge.

Comment: for future reference, there is a http fuzzer now: https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz-http

Answer (score 1):

If you Google "http protocol format", the first result right now is [this HTTP tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_messages.htm). If you read a few pages there, you can get a pretty good description of the protocol format. Based on that, I wrote the following fuzz script, [source code here](https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz-http):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Designed for use with boofuzz v0.0.9
from boofuzz import *


def main():
    session = Session(
        target=Target(
            connection=SocketConnection("127.0.0.1", 80, proto='tcp')
        ),
    )

    s_initialize(name="Request")
    with s_block("Request-Line"):
        s_group("Method", ['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'CONNECT', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE'])
        s_delim(" ", name='space-1')
        s_string("/index.html", name='Request-URI')
        s_delim(" ", name='space-2')
        s_string('HTTP/1.1', name='HTTP-Version')
        s_static("\r\n", name="Request-Line-CRLF")
    s_static("\r\n", "Request-CRLF")

    session.connect(s_get("Request"))

    session.fuzz()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Although I got tripped up for a while because I only had one CRLF. After checking [RFC 2616 (Section 5)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5), it's pretty clear that this example should end with two CRLFs.

```
    Request       = Request-Line              ; Section 5.1
                    *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                     | request-header         ; Section 5.3
                     | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                    CRLF
                    [ message-body ]          ; Section 4.3

    [...]

    Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF
```

Obviously, this fuzz script doesn't come close to covering the whole protocol. Just a few things that could be added:

1. HTTP Headers (there are a lot)
2. Specialized formats for each HTTP Method
3. A message body (e.g. on POST)
4. Some way to choose valid URIs for the particular target server
5. Report warnings based on server response (could get noisy, but server errors do tend to indicate... errors)

Comment: Regarding an example with a message body - one exists in the boofuzz repo under examples: [http-with-body](https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz/blob/master/examples/http_with_body.py)